# Is this program tail recursive?

Tags: recursion, language-agnostic

My friend and I were arguing over whether an algorithm we had to analyze for homework was tail-recursive or not, but he insist that it is. So, the algorithm looks something like this:

```
SomeAlgo(x)
{
   x--;

   if (x > 1)
   {
      SomeAlgo(x);
   }
   else
   {
      return x;
   }
}
```

I told him it wasn't tail recursive, because SomeAlgo(x) wasn't the last statement to be executed. We need a base case, but we don't. If we had a base case, the code in the base case would be the first thing to be executed and the call to itself (which returns the value to be returned) would be the last.

If it's not tail-recursive, can you tell me what needs to be done to make it tail-recursive?

Comment: What programming language is this?  You'll get more views if you specify the programming language you are using in the tags.

Answer (score 3):

SomeAlgo(x) *is* the last statement to be executed, if X is greater than 1.

Comment: I thought you needed to have return algo(x) in order to have a tail recursive algorithm. The last statement that is executed is return x and not algo(x). Am I wrong?

Comment: If the only possible way for an algorithm to use tail recursion was to return another call to itself, then every implementation of "tail recursion" would result in infinite recursion, and thus a stackoverflowerror, because it would never be able to return a static value. In the case of your algorithm, `return x;` where x <= 1 is your base case.

Comment: So else return x is the base case, right? But it's not the first statement to be executed, it's the last line of code that's executed, right?

Comment: When x <= 1, yes, it is the last thing to be executed.

Comment: Then it's not tail recursive.

Comment: You could always just change it to `SomeAlgo(x) { x--; if (x <= 1) { return x; } return SomeAlgo(x); }` if you really wanted the call to SomeAlgo to be the last thing in the function. It would have the exact same effect though.

Comment: Ah, maybe I didn't understand what tail-recursion meant. Someone told me that an algorithm was tail recursive if the last statement was always a call to itself.

Comment: That's not entirely a wrong definition. But there does have to be a terminating condition, ie a base case, otherwise the recursion would just go on forever, never actually returning anything.

Comment: The issue isn't what the source looks like, but how it's compiled.  Any decent optimizer will compile either @jonhopkins version or the original with a tail-recursive call, and optimize it into an loop.  Check out Wikipedia's [Tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion) article.